# update parent child data nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new in mongodb with nodejs.I want to update the comments data.Here is my document

```
 {
       "__v": NumberInt(0),
       "_id": ObjectId("565443b1172e19d51f98b0ed"),
       "address": "tohana",
       "comments": [
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("5654455fe088d89c20736e3c"),
           "comment": "good man",
           "uemail": "dinesh@gmail.com",
           "uname": "dinesh" 
        },
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("565445e471dce6ca20705a84"),
           "comment": "nice person",
           "uemail": "kr@gmail.com",
           "uname": "krishan" 
        },
         {
           "_id": ObjectId("5654460e7aa73bec2064060e"),
           "comment": "bad person",
           "uemail": "Rai",
           "uname": "Rahul" 
        } 
      ],
       "email": "nishantg@ocodewire.com"▼,
       "name": "Nishant" 
    }
```

I am using Angular js in frontend and nodeJs as backend. Here is my code:

```
app.post('/commentsSave/:id', function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id; // userId
var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //commentData
var commentId = input.id; //commentId
var name  = input.name;
var email = input.email;
var comment = input.comment
res.send({data:id,data2:input});

})
```

Comment: can you add your mongoose model and you mean you just want to update comments in existing dcoument?

Comment: I have already add mongoose model.I just want to update comment.. @prasun

Comment: do you want to use mongoose or mongodb native driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.post('/commentsSave/:id', function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id; // userId
        var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //commentData
        var commentId = input.id; //commentId
        var name  = input.name;
        var email = input.email;
        var comment = input.comment
        Users.update({'comments._id': input.id}, 
        {
            $set: {
                'comments.$.name': name,
                'comments.$.email': email,
                'comments.$.comment': comment
                }
        },function(error, result){
          if(error){
            console.log(error);
          }
          else{
           console.log(result);
          }
     })
}
```